# Avoid rails making extra queries json include statements by using join

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Right now i am getting the 25 most recent posts

```
posts = Post.where(public: true).limit(25).order(created_at: :desc)
```

and when i am rendering it i use an include

```
render :json => posts.as_json(:include => [:user])
```

this is to get the user who made the post and send it ie:

```
{
      "id": 43,
      "title": "asdfasdfs",
      "story": "adfaf sdf sd asdf sdf asdf saf adf",
      "created_at": "2017-05-10T22:40:54.587Z",
      "user": {
        "id": 4,
        "first_name": "heelo",
        "last_name": "heelo",
}
```

which looks like it works great but when looking in the console. its making 26 queries, one to get the posts,

```
 SELECT  "posts".* FROM "posts" WHERE (public = true) ORDER BY "posts"."created_at" DESC LIMIT ?  [["LIMIT", 25]]
```

and 25 more to get the user for each post

```
 SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["id", XXX], ["LIMIT", 1]]
```

to gets its user. Isnt there some way i can do a join to avoid making 25 more queries. i tried

```
posts = Post.joins(:user).where(public: true).limit(25).order(created_at: :desc)
```

but it doesnt seem to do anything.
Any advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `includes` to cut it down to only two queries.

```
posts = Post.includes(:user).where(public: true).limit(25).order(created_at: :desc)
```

This will query the last 25 posts in one query and all the associated users in another query.